# ERROR! Installing node serialPort On raspberry Pi 3 model b

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, iot, node-serialport

I am doing an IoT project with raspberry Pi and `arduino.in` this case I need to work with both `WebSocket` and `SerialPort` modules. because those modules are required to communicate with Samsung Artik. but the problem is when I am trying to install `serialPort` it is getting following error continuously. I looked for all the GitHub forums for the solutions and they were not working. Does anyone get a solution for this? Thanks in advance. refer the error log for node versions and other details.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo -i

SSH is enabled and the default password for the 'pi' user has not been changed.
This is a security risk - please login as the 'pi' user and type 'passwd' to set                                                                                         a new password.

root@raspberrypi:~# sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm serialport
(node:1740) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpd                                                                                        ir() instead.
npm ERR! Error: Method Not Allowed
npm ERR!     at errorResponse (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:260:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:203:12
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.j                                                                                        s:167:7)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.14.50-v7+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "--unsafe-perm" "                                                                                        serialport"
npm ERR! cwd /root
npm ERR! node -v v8.11.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E405
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
root@raspberrypi:~# ^C
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

**Screenshot of error:**

[image: Screenshot of error log]

raspberry pi 3 model B board has latest RASPBIAN OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update npm to the latest release worked for me :

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

and :: 
    "npm install -g **--unsafe-perm**  serialport"

used node and npm version on a raspbian installation when a got the same error you described :

```
npm ERR! System Linux 4.14.69-v7+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "serialport"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/html/plugins/rflink/resources
npm ERR! node -v v8.11.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E405
```

Comment: Weird, a reasonably recent Node but a completely outdated npm.

Comment: Thanks for all providing helpful answer(s) and comment(s).I finally solved the error using the following steps. First Step - `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential`  I used those commands to install Node version 6. Step 2 - `sudo npm install -g node-gyp
sudo npm install -g node-pre-gyp` This will install node-gyp globally.as the Step 3- `sudo npm install serialport --unsafe-perm`. Those steps finally worked for me.try them on if you troubling with this error. Thanks again.